# embedding a tikzpicture into a commutative diagram with arrows from internal nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, commutative-diagrams

This is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass[border=1 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=normal]
        \textbf{TCRS} \arrow[rr,"\mathcal{TRSC}"] \arrow[dr,swap,"localize"]&& \text{TPF} \\
        & \textbf{TDRS}  \arrow[ur,swap,"\mathcal{TRSC}"]&
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I need to do is :

1- substituting the following to the lower `TDRS` node,

```
\documentclass[border=1 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{bigbox} = [draw=blue!50, thick, rounded corners, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{box} = [draw=blue!50, minimum size=0.6cm, rounded corners,rectangle]
%
\matrix[row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm, inner sep=2mm, bigbox] {
    \node {\textbf{TDRS}};\\
    \node[box] {$\textbf{LOC}^{P}$};\\
    \node[box] {$\textbf{LOC}^{C}$};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2- rearranging the outflow arrows of the new node like the following.

[image]

According to what CarLaTeX did [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348676/adding-symbols-wherever-i-want-in-a-commutative-diagram), the idea is seemingly just putting the `tikzpicture` environment of the new node instead of the primary one. I did it as the snippet below:

```
\documentclass[border=1 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=normal]
        \textbf{TCRS} \arrow[rr,"\mathcal{TRSC}"] \arrow[dr,swap,"localize"]&& \text{TPF} \\
        & {\begin{tikzpicture}
            \tikzstyle{bigbox} = [draw=blue!50, thick, rounded corners, rectangle]
            \tikzstyle{box} = [draw=blue!50, minimum size=0.6cm, rounded corners,rectangle]
            %
            \matrix[row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm, inner sep=2mm, bigbox] {
                \node {\textbf{TDRS}};\\
                \node[box] {$\textbf{LOC}^{P}$};\\
                \node[box] {$\textbf{LOC}^{C}$};\\
            };
            \end{tikzpicture}}  \arrow[ur,swap,"\mathcal{TRSC}"]&
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

but the result is the most disasterous thing I've ever seen:

[image]

and the compiler syas: `Package pgf Error: You cannot nest pgfmatrix environments.`

Furthermore, I have no idea how to draw those two dahsed arrows.

Any help?!

Comment: `tikzcd` environment fundamentally is a `tikz matrix`, and `tikz` matrices can't be nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't expect reasonable output when you get an error ...

You can build the diagram using plain TikZ instead, or you can save the `\matrix` in a box, and use that in `tikz-cd`. The start and end point of arrows can be customized with `start anchor` and `end anchor`.

Left, TikZ, right `tikz-cd`. (I see the font size could be reduced in some of the nodes in the first case.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newsavebox\MyMatrix
\savebox{\MyMatrix}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  bigbox/.style={draw=blue!50, thick, rounded corners, rectangle},
  box/.style={draw=blue!50, minimum size=0.6cm, rounded corners,rectangle}
]

\matrix[row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm, inner sep=2mm, bigbox] {
   \node {\textbf{TDRS}};\\
   \node[box] {$\textbf{LOC}^{P}$};\\
   \node[box] {$\textbf{LOC}^{C}$};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  bigbox/.style={draw=blue!50, thick, rounded corners, rectangle},
  box/.style={draw=blue!50, minimum size=0.6cm, rounded corners,rectangle}
]
            %
\node (a) {\textbf{TCRS}};
\node [right=5cm of a.center,anchor=center] (b) {TPF};

\matrix (m) [below right=2cm and 2.5cm of a.center,anchor=north,row sep=2mm, column sep=2mm, inner sep=2mm, bigbox] {
                \node (m1) {\textbf{TDRS}};\\
                \node (m2) [box] {$\textbf{LOC}^{P}$};\\
                \node (m3) [box] {$\textbf{LOC}^{C}$};\\
            };


\draw [->] (a) -- node[above] {$\mathcal{TRSC}$} (b);
\draw [->] (a) -- node[left] {localize} (m);
\draw [->,dashed] (m1.south east) -- node[right] {$\mathcal{TRSC}$} (b.south west);
\draw [->,dashed] (m3.north east) -- (b.south);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=normal]
    \textbf{TCRS} \arrow[rr,"\mathcal{TRSC}"] \arrow[dr,swap,"\text{localize}"]&& \text{TPF} \\
     & \usebox{\MyMatrix} 
     \arrow[ur,dashed,"\mathcal{TRSC}"swap,start anchor={[shift={(-5mm,-7mm)}]north east},end anchor={[xshift=2mm]south west}]
     \arrow[ur,dashed,start anchor={[shift={(-4mm,-17mm)}]north east}, end anchor={[xshift=-4mm]south east}]
     \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Every answer = a lot of things to learn` I've never heard of the notion of "saving in a box" before.

Comment: @Roboticist Often comes up on questions that ask about nesting `tikzpicture`s (which one should in general avoid, but boxing like this is one way of getting around the problems that occur when it's done).

Answer (score 1):

```
        \documentclass[12pt,letterpaper ,oneside ,openany]{book}

    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{color}

    % *************************  TiKz  *************************
    % *************************  TiKz  *************************
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,chains,mindmap,trees,backgrounds,shapes.geometric, arrows,arrows.meta, calc,plotmarks,intersections,shadows.blur,decorations.pathmorphing}

    \newcommand{\TikZGuide}[8]{
    \draw[dashed,line width=0.1pt,gray] ({#5},{#6}) grid [xstep=0.5cm, ystep=0.5cm] ({#3},{#4});
    \draw[help lines,line width=0.1pt,red!50] ({#1},{#2}) grid ({#3},{#4});
    \draw[help lines,line width=0.1pt,blue] ({#5},{#6}) grid ({#7},{#8}); 
    }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                     background rectangle/.style={fill=green!20!white},                    
                     show background rectangle]     

    %% A grid -- Just for Guides that help to locate points:
    %\TikZGuide{0}{0}{8}{8}{-8}{-6}{0}{0}                   
    \def\Y{yellow}
    \def\xTCRS{-3}; \def\yTCRS{2}
    \def\xTPF{3}; \def\yTPF{2}
    \def\colorA{red!70!white}
    \def\colorB{red!70!white}
        \node (A) at (0,0) {};
        \node[below of = A] (B){};  
        \node[below of = B] (C){};      
        \node[below of = C] (D){};      
        \node[below of = D] (E){};
    \draw[fill = gray!20!white] (-1.5,0.5) rectangle (1.5,-3);
    \node (A2) at (\xTCRS,\yTCRS) {\textbf{TCRS}};
    \node (B2) at (\xTPF,\yTPF) {\textbf{TCPF}};    
    \draw[-latex, thick, blue] (A2) -- node[above]{$\mathcal{TRSC}$}(B2);
    \draw[-latex, thick, red] (A2) -- node[below left]{$\textit{Localize}$}(A);

    \draw[-latex, dashed,thick, red,above right] (B) -- node[below right]{$\textit{TRSC}$}(B2); 
    \draw[-latex, dashed,thick, purple,right] (C) -- (B2);  
    \draw[] (A) node[inner sep=4pt,rounded corners=3pt] {\large \textbf{TDRS} };
    \draw[] (B) node[inner sep=4pt,rounded corners=3pt,white,fill=\colorA] {\large $\mathbf{LOC}^{P}$ };
    \draw[] (C) node[inner sep=4pt,rounded corners=3pt,white,fill=\colorB] {\large $\mathbf{LOC}^{C}$ };

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]